# Time of columns multiplication by indices in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, profiling, multiple-columns

Why is so much time spent on the multiplication of columns in the case of the column index using in a cycle? What can be done to reduce the execution time of this part?

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
 8                                           @profile
 9                                           def zero_one_two(grid, N):
10     23810       236265      9.9      1.1      if 1 in grid[:, 0]:
11       731         9416     12.9      0.0          grid[:, 0][np.where(grid[:, 0] > 0)[0]] = 2
12     23810       201348      8.5      0.9      left_con = grid[:, 0]*grid[:, 1]
13     23810       195165      8.2      0.9      left_true_indices = np.where(left_con > 0)[0]
14     23810        49803      2.1      0.2      if left_true_indices.size:
15     16896        68303      4.0      0.3          grid[:, 0][left_true_indices] = 2
16     16896        56940      3.4      0.3          grid[:, 1][left_true_indices] = 2
17    861832      1671442      1.9      7.5      for j in np.arange(1, N-1):
18    838022      6193150      7.4     27.8          col_mult = grid[:, j] * grid[:, j+1]
19    838022      6079750      7.3     27.3          col_mult_true_indices = np.where(col_mult > 1)[0]
20    838022      1591003      1.9      7.1          if col_mult_true_indices.size:
21     94221       337757      3.6      1.5              grid[:, j][col_mult_true_indices] = 2
22     94221       377351      4.0      1.7              grid[:, j+1][col_mult_true_indices] = 2
23     94221       653747      6.9      2.9              col_con = grid[:-1, j]*grid[1:, j]
24     94221       694403      7.4      3.1              col_con_indices = np.where(col_con == 2)[0]
25     94221       490465      5.2      2.2              col_con_indices2 = col_con_indices + 1
26     94221       352366      3.7      1.6              grid[:, j][col_con_indices] = 2
27     94221       302229      3.2      1.4              grid[:, j][col_con_indices2] = 2
28     94221       757152      8.0      3.4              col_con2 = grid[:-1, j+1]*grid[1:, j+1]
29     94221       691756      7.3      3.1              col_con2_indices = np.where(col_con2 == 2)[0]
30     94221       482827      5.1      2.2              col_con2_indices2 = col_con2_indices + 1
31     94221       414628      4.4      1.9              grid[:, j+1][col_con2_indices] = 2
32     94221       371939      3.9      1.7              grid[:, j+1][col_con2_indices2] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you want to multiply each column with the column left of it. This multiplication can be done much faster at once by multiplying two subsets of the original grid with each other. You can also do this for the first N columns of the grid:

```
    grid_col_mult = grid[:,0:N]*grid[:,1:N+1]
```